# How do I create a custom global element/app within CRM Dynamics such that it shows on all pages and can control user navigation?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I need to add a custom element/mini-app/extension to CRM Dynamics sales such that it shows globally on all pages that the user navigates to and also can navigate the users urls when certain events happen.

What options exactly do I have to satisfy the above criteria?

The screenshot below shows a sample area that I need to build the app within as an example. 
[image: Crm Lead Page with custom widget]

Id imagine there are many use cases where customizing a global element is worthwhile, especially since custom applications may need to be built.

I understand I can use the Resources to create a SPA such as angular which is running so long as the URL stays at the SPA url. But for our use case, we are looking to allow end users to be able to navigate the CRM using the custom controls. but when something happens in a another subsystem, we need end users who are logged into the CRM to instantly view data that is important to them.

Is this technically possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not feasible. There are some concepts to show learning path like that. It won’t satisfy your need.

I understand what you need, like a news feed or ad rotator for rolling content but context specific flyout area which is always pinned. There is no OOB option or customization/configuration available for achieving this. You can initiate this concept in [Dynamics Ideas](https://experience.dynamics.com/ideas/).

Like you said there can be a HTML web resource developed & embedded in a dashboard, this is very limited for your requirement.

**Edit**:

I think you are looking for [Channel Integration Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/channel-integration-framework/overview-channel-integration-framework) which will help you to configure third party CTI apps.

Comment: It’s hard to accept as truth the idea that this is not feasible, since I have seen two companies who have apparently accomplished this. Five9 Adapter for Microsoft Dynamics CRM and InteractionSync for PureCloud.

Comment: @joey sorry if I misunderstood. Are you talking about this: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/dynamics-365/five9.9356f21b-29fb-4a1a-8b00-a4cbefcba676?tab=Overview?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I am referring to. They accomplished this in some way. How did they technically implement this?

Comment: woaw @Arun Winoth, this is an amazing find. Thank you so much. Do you know of any others? How did you locate this?

Comment: @joey I don’t have any idea other than pure luck. Maybe your luck :) I remember I read somewhere in my LinkedIn feed in the past, though could not get the exact search string. But still not sure if that is available for non-CTI requirements

Answer (score 0):

In CRM V9, they have introduced a new API call for 'Panel'.  This panel loads to the side of the screen, and can display content regardless of where the user moves throughout the entire application.  I've played around with it a bit for my own person reasons at work, but it looks to be exactly what you're looking for.

The call is 'Xrm.Panel.loadPanel(URL/WebResource)'

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/xrm-panel
[image: Example]

However, the feature is currently in development, and should only be used in production at your own risk.